# Android system is killing my app process when it is minimized on Nexus 5

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I create simple app what have functionality show some news and play music in background. The problem is: an all test devices app work fine, but on Nexus 5 with Android 5.0.1 system kill my app process when it is minimized (home button pressed), and music music off, and app restart when I unminimize it. I can reproduce it almost 100% by duing next steps:
1) press home in my app. 2) open Gmail client. 3) Open web-browser with some heavy web-site by click on link in email.
My app does not use largeHeap flag or some heavy images. I suggested that this happens becouse the phone RAM is over. I have installed first app from market for request "memory usage". It show next on Nexus 5 after killing my app:

> Total: 1856Mb, Avail: 429Mb, Inact: 156Mb, Act: 842Mb, thres: 219Mb,
>   Low: no.

I don't really understend this values (429+156+842+219 = 1646, not 1856), but looks like there is enough memory.

I can't understand why system on phone with 2Gb RAM memory, with only few running app kill the small app what was used few minutes ago and moreover - play music in background, but on older devices everything is ok, or mayby I did something wrong?

UPD. Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxxxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name=".xxxxxx"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
      <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="xxxxxx" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LauncherActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Launcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your manifest.xml file.

Comment: Possibly related: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1701 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79729

Answer (score 0):

If your application is playing music, and i assume you're playing that music and doing your operations on a Service, have this service get foreground priority, example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

This way the system won't kill your service unless the world is ending and the whole thing just crashes :)

One little note though, having a foreground service requires a persistent notification which you have a button in it that closes this service for example.